# How hold data after submit admin site form

Tags: django, django-models

Here is the screenshot of my project with model.py.

when i click the "save and add another button" then the values of "Lev name:" "Sem name:" "SType:" changed to its default value.
what should i do?

so that the given value will not change to default values.

Comment: Don't use pictures to show your code, paste your code inside your question using SO's markup tools.

Comment: I don't understand your question. This is the expected behavior of pressing 'save and add another' in the admin interface: It saves the course you just created and gives you a new empty form to create the next course.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the defaults in the form to be the values from the last entry, you need to customize your form in the `ModelAdmin`. Probably the easiest would be to [use your own form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) to change the `initial` value. Something like:

```
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CourseForm

class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        try:
             last_course = Course.objects.last()
             initial = {'sem_name': last_course.sem_name, 'sType': last_course.sType}
        except Course.DoesNotExist:
             initial = None
        super(CourseForm, self).__init__(initial=initial, **kwargs)
```